# If $A(t)\in SO(3)$, why is $\dot{A}(t)A(t)^{-1}\in\mathfrak{so}(3)$?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am going through [some notes on geometric mechanics](http://www.math.univ-metz.fr/ecoles/monastir05-dir/notes/CoursTudorRatiu.pdf). In the first section we let $A(t)$ denote some product of Euler rotations:
$$
A(t)=
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \cos (\psi ) \cos (\varphi )-\cos (\theta ) \sin (\varphi ) \sin (\psi ) & \cos (\psi ) \sin (\varphi )+\cos (\theta ) \cos (\varphi ) \sin (\psi ) & \sin (\theta ) \sin (\psi ) \\
 -\cos (\theta ) \cos (\psi ) \sin (\varphi )+\cos (\varphi ) (-\sin (\psi )) & \cos (\theta ) \cos (\varphi ) \cos (\psi )-\sin (\psi ) \sin (\varphi ) & \sin (\theta ) \cos (\psi ) \\
 \sin (\theta ) \sin (\varphi ) & -\sin (\theta ) \cos (\varphi ) & \cos (\theta )
\end{array}\right),
$$
where $0<\psi(t),\varphi(t)<2\pi$, $0<\theta(t)<\pi$ are Euler angles. This implies that $A(t)\in SO(3)$, the special orthogonal Lie group in three dimensions.

Later on we consider the quantities
$$\omega_S(t)=\dot{A}(t)A^{-1}(t),$$
$$\omega_B(t)=A^{-1}(t)\dot{A}(t),$$
where the dot indicates the time derivative. We can verify through direct calculation that $\omega_S(t),\omega_B(t)\in\mathfrak{so}(3)$, the lie algebra of skew-symmetric matrices in three dimensions. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with the defining property of the orthogonal group:  that $A(t) A^T(t) = I$, where the $^T$ indicates the transpose.  Suppressing the $t$, we get $AA^t  = I$.

Take the derivative of this equation.  You get $A' A^T + A (A^T)' = 0$.

Now, an easy calculation shows $(A^T)' = (A')^T$, so this turns into $A' A^T + A(A')^T = 0$.  Using the fact that $(BC)^T = C^T B^T$, we can rewrite this as $A' A^T + (A' A^T)^T = 0$.  In other words, $A'A^T$ is skew symmetric, so is an element of $\mathfrak{so}(n)$.

But, $A^T = A^{-1}$ for $A\in SO(n)$, so we have $A'A^{-1}\in \mathfrak{so}(n)$.

Comment: Thanks for that. Do you know if there is any deeper way to look at this problem? I mean in the sense that as $A(t)\in SO(3)$ we would expect $\dot{A}(t)$ to have something to do with the tangent space at the identity $\mathfrak{so}(3)$?

Comment: Sure.  If $A(t_0) = I$ for some particular $t_0$, then $A'(t_0)\in \mathfrak{so}(n)$, essentially by definition.  If $A(t_0)\neq I$, then we can fix it by considering either $A^{-1}(t_0) A(t)$ or $A(t) A^{-1}(t_0)$  Then the derivate is either $A^{-1}(t_0) A'(t)$ or $A'(t) A^{-1}(t_0)$ (because $A^{-1}(t_0)$ is a constant), so these should be elements of $\mathfrak{so}(n)$.